# Inferring a digit in a long integer sequence created by a pattern of digits

Tags: sequences-and-series

If you concatenate all even numbers in sequence to form a long sequence it would start like this:  $2468101214161820$.

What is the $2018$th digit?  I know there should be an easy pattern.  I need to explain this to middle school students, so the easier the explanation the better!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are $4$ even digits, and $45$ two digit even numbers.  That's $4+2\times 45=94$ digits accounted for.  Then there are $450$ three digit even numbers. (Why?  Well the $n^{th}$ even three digit number is $100+2\times (n-1)$ so we just need to solve $100+2\times (n-1)=998\implies n=450$). That's another $3\times 450=1350$ digits so we have accounted for $1350+94=1444$ digits altogether.

You want digit number $2018$ which is $2018-1444=574$ digits further down.  Thus your digit occurs in a four digit even number.  Which one?  Well, of course each four digit numbers accounts for $4$ more digits so the first $\frac {572}4=143$ four digit numbers get you within two.  Thus your digit is the second from the left of the $144^{th}$ even four digit number.  As that four digit number is $1000-2\times (144-1)=1286$ the answer you want is $$\boxed {2}$$

Note:  this argument, while elementary, is extremely error prone.  I'd check it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There are $4$ one-digit even numbers.  There are $45$ two-digit even numbers. (They run from $10$ to $98$.  For counting them, it's easier to divide by $2$ and count the number from $5$ to $49$.)  There are $450$ three-digit even even numbers.  (Use the same trick.)

So far, we have$$4\cdot1+45\cdot2+450\cdot3=1444$$  digits, so we need another $$2018-1444=574$$ digits.  Since $574=4*143+2$ we are looking for the second digit of the $144$th four-digit even number.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I almost always make an off by one error in questions like this, but I think there are $450$ three digit even numbers.  They are given by $100+2(n-1)$ as $n$ runs from $1$ to $450$.   No?

Comment: Note:  just to be sure, I put it up on a spreadsheet.  Just listed all $450$ even two digit numbers.  But even your argument yields $450$.  Dividing by $2$ we see we want to count the number between $50$ and $499$.  Taking the difference we do get $449$ but you have to add $1$ to that, just as you added $1$ after subtracting $49-5=44$ to get $45$.

Comment: @lulu You are right, of course.  The first time through, I got $450$ but for some reason, I changed my mind when I was typing it out.  I see that wasn't the only mistake I made; I must have been punchy.  I hope I've fixed it now.

Comment: I find problems like this more error prone than just about any other sort.  Easy to come very close, of course.